# "Piecewise" in "ProbabilityDistribution" would not affect the result

Tags: probability-or-statistics, piecewise

```mathematica
D[Probability[Sin[X] < y, 
   Distributed[X, 
    ProbabilityDistribution[
     Piecewise[{{2*x/(Pi^2), 0 < x < Pi}, {0, 
        x <= 0 || x >= Pi}}], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]]], 
  y] // Simplify
```

produces
$$\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
  & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{2}{\pi  \sqrt{1-y^2}} & 0<y<1 \\
 0 & y>1\lor y<0 \\
 \text{Indeterminate} & \text{True} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}\right.$$

However,

```mathematica
D[Probability[Sin[X] < y, 
   Distributed[X, 
    ProbabilityDistribution[
     Piecewise[{{2*x/(Pi^2), 0 < x < Pi}}], {x, -Infinity, 
      Infinity}]]], y] // Simplify
```

produces the same result. I guess in the first example, the `Piecewise` doesn't work. In the first example, the right answer should be

$$\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
  & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{2}{\pi  \sqrt{1-y^2}} & 0<y<1 \\
 0 & y\ge1\lor y\le0 \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}\right.$$

Comment: Since the default for `Piecewise` is the value zero, the two `Piecewise` statements are equivalent, i.e., "Piecewise[{{2*x/(Pi^2), 0 < x < Pi}, {0, x <= 0 || x >= Pi}}] === 
 Piecewise[{{2*x/(Pi^2), 0 < x < Pi}}]` evaluates to `True`

Comment: @BobHanlon: Did you pay your attention to my answer submitted before your comment?

Comment: @user64494 I think his/her comment is imortant here, but as there is one condition applied, so the default value for `Piecewise` shouldn't work here. Why does the default value zero does work in this situation?

Answer (score 5):

Mathematica is right in both cases, you are not. First,

```
FullSimplify[ Piecewise[{{2*x/(Pi^2), 0 < x < Pi}, {0, x <= 0 || x >= Pi}}]- 
Piecewise[{{2*x/(Pi^2), 0 < x < Pi}}]]
```

> `0`

and this explains the identical results (also look in the documentation to `Piecewise` for info). Second,

```
Probability[Sin[X] < y,  Distributed[X,  ProbabilityDistribution[ 
Piecewise[{{2*x/(Pi^2), 0 < x < Pi}, {0,  x <= 0 || x >= Pi}}], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]]]
```

> `Piecewise[{{1, y > 1},  {(2*ArcSin[y])/Pi, Inequality[0,  Less, y, LessEqual, 1]}}, 0]`

and the plot

```
Plot[Piecewise[{{1, y > 1}, {(2*ArcSin[y])/Pi, 
Inequality[0, Less, y, LessEqual, 1]}}, 0], {y, -1, 2}, 
 WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision, PlotPoints -> 200]
```

[image]

clearly shows its non-differentiability at `y==0` and `y==1` (rigorous proof on demand).